# Accessing variables in an asynchronous function without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, parameter-passing

How can I access variables in an asynchronous function declared previously? I suppose I have to pass them as parameters but how do I do this?

The problem is, by the time `http` is loaded, `i` and other data has changed since the function call is asynchronous.

```
var myDataInitializedBefore = ...;

for (var i = 0; i < myDataInitializedBefore.length; ++i)
{
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", myUrl, true);
    http.responseType = "blob";
    http.onload = function(e) 
    {
        if (this.status == 200)
        {
            --> do something with myDataInitializedBefore[i] and some other variables
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will work, as you have it :)

Comment: @bluehipy nope it wont...

Comment: the local var will be accessible as you describe but it will not work as you expect as i will have the value from the end of the loop.

Comment: Your suggested solution shows only how to call a simple function within a closure. Using closures with `XMLHttpRequests` WITHOUT jQuery is not trivial.